# Xamarin Comma to Dot replace ( listview in mvvm )

Tags: xamarin

I have a listview as below. In this listview, I have an entry, and I don’t want to let the users to write comma (,) in the entry ( only dot will be allowed).
Can I do it with entry trigger? Or how I will do it. If the entry wouldn’t be inside the listview, I would use text_changed event or I would control it with the Inotifipropertychanged interface in ViewModel side.
But now I’m curious to know how can I do it in listview?

Thanks in advance.

```
                 <ListView   HasUnevenRows="True"  ItemsSource="{Binding SALES_LIST }"   >

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                            <DataTemplate >
                                <ViewCell IsEnabled="True"    >

                                    <Entry   Text="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay}"/>


                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: It can be done by an AttachedProperty or create a NumberEntry class inherited from Entry and implement this behavior there

Comment: i solved it with  <Entry.Behaviors>   thank you sir. it s working great.